# Passing parameters to a database backend in Django

Tags: django, multithreading, backend, middleware

I have created a Django backend to manage databases. I need to be able to pass values to it based on the user. I have created this Middleware for that purpose, and it behaves correctly in the development environment, PyCharm. The question is, will it work correctly in production if it's running with multiple threads since I'm using Gunicorn?

My code, I use the session variable SESSION_B2J for this, and from the backend, I call get_session_b2j to retrieve values:

```
import threading


def get_session_b2j():
    thread_local = B2jBakendMiddleware.thread_local
    if hasattr(thread_local, 'session_b2j'):
        return thread_local.session_b2j


def set_session_b2j(session_b2j):
    thread_local = B2jBakendMiddleware.thread_local
    thread_local.session_b2j = session_b2j


class B2jBakendMiddleware(object):
    thread_local = threading.local()

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        self.thread_local.session_b2j = request.session.get('SESSION_B2J')
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```